# how can I add a span to a dynamic menu in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, menu

I have a dynamic menu in wordpress using `wp_nav_menu`, however I would like to add a span to just one of the list items.

I will demonstrate this in static HTML to show you what I would like to achieve.

I currently have this...

```
<li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
```

...but would like to achieve this...

```
<li><a href="#">Test<span>(icon)</span></a></li>
```

Is there anyway to do this dynamically?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have a look at this almost identical question on Wordpress Answers: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/44956/how-to-apply-a-class-to-the-second-word-in-menu-list-item/44972#44972

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Am I understanding the example correctly that you want an image icon inside the span?  If so you could just use the wordpress generated class/ID for that specific li or anchor tag and give it a right aligned background image with CSS.  You may have to also set it to have a wider width to accommodate the image.  You wouldn't even need to add a span tag.

**Here's the modified answer to give you want you want since my previous answer wasn't quite what you're looking for:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery('#menu-item-175 a').append('<span></span>')
</script>
```

Just change the #menu-item-175 to the correct ID of the li that surrounds the anchor you want to append to.

Comment: thanks but I am using an icon font, and would like the icon font to change with the text on hover

Comment: I don't fully understand what you're after, but my modified answer will add your span tag.  Please see above for my modified answer.

Comment: I hadn't considered using jquery but am already using it on the same page and definitely solves the problem. Thanks for this!

Comment: I think jQuery is a lazy way out here. It is clearly a matter of presentation, so it should be done in CSS (as you say at the beginning of your answer). If additional markup is required, it should be done in the theme's PHP code.

Comment: CSS would have been the route I personally would have tried to take, hence my first answer.  If it is a single list item he wants to target jQuery is not necessarily the "lazy" way out, its certainly the most simple, but I wouldn't go as far as to say lazy.  In any case, it achieved what he was looking for, no harm no foul.  Glad I could help.